# Allow unauthenticated access to a single endpoint without .antMatchers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

So, is there a way of allowing unauthenticated access to a single endpoint?
I have a Spring Security Configuration class like this:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And a controller that looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/users")
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping
    public List<Users> getUserList(@PathVariable String userId) {
        return this.userService.getUserList(userId);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        this.userService.createUser(user);
    }

}
```

Therefore, using `antMatchers` inside my config probably won't do the job, as both my `GET` and `POST` have the same path... Is there a way I can disable security on a single endpoint, like a decorator on something like that?

Btw, I'm working with Java 19 and Spring's latest stable version as of March/2023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overload of antMatcher that [takes the http method as first param](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html#antMatcher(org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,java.lang.String)), try:

```
antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/users").permitAll()
```

Comment: Does that mean that, if I need to add 100 endpoints to that, I'll need to repeat that 100 times? Isn't there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: You can still use wildcards on the path variable. Very wild cards if you like.